# can't find the usb_driver folder, please install the Google USB Driver Packager using the Android SDK manager windows 7 32

Tags: usb, driver, packager

After getting my app to work in the emulator, I now want to test it on my Sony Xperia Arc Android phone. I follow the instructions from google here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html but can't get their USB driver to load.

When I plug the phone into the computer via the supplied USB data cable, Windows 7 installs it's own driver and doesn't give me a chance to point to the google driver located here: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf.

When I go to the device manager and right-click on the Device Manage and try to Update Driver Software to point to the Google driver, it says it already has the best one and won't change it! (even though it doesn't work, ie. no drive label appears for the phone plus the device manager shows an ! for it)

I've spent many hours reading dozens of posts with similar problems but no solutions work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Download the drivers from here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/cws/devworld/downloads/download/sonyericssonxperiaarcxperianeoxperiaplaydrivers